# Java: removing the first word in split

Tags: java, regex, split

i want to **split a String by whitespaces and remove the First match**.
Since doing this seperatly would be in O(n) i wonder **if there is a Regex for doing this?**

e.g.:

```
String s = "asd wer gfb";
String sA[] = s.split(magixRegex);
```

than sA should contain:

```
["wer", "gfb"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the first word and then do splitting.

```
String s = "asd wer gfb";
String sA[] = s.replaceFirst("^\\S+\\s*", "").split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sA));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could substring it first:

```
String s = "asd wer gfb";
s = s.substring( s.indexOf(' ') + 1 );
String sA[] = s.split(" ");
```